# keyboard popup its hide last row of grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have using AppCompact Themes in xamarin forms android when  keyboard popup its hide last row of grid
[Before Keyboard Popup see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOILG.png)

Below is my code. I've created the grid having title, description. I want to show the camera icon and its bar above the keyboard when it comes and go back to the bottom of the screen when the keyboard hides.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="0"
            Padding="10,8"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Entry
                x:Name="GeneralPostTitle"
                Margin="10,10,10,0"
                FontSize="20"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Placeholder="Title"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                TextColor="Black"
                VerticalOptions="End" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="10,0"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Spacing="0"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                <customRenderer:PlaceholderEditor
                    x:Name="EditorDescription"
                    Margin="10,10,10,0"
                    FontSize="22"
                    HeightRequest="130"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Placeholder="Add Description"
                    PlaceholderTextColor="Gray"
                    TextColor="Gray" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout
                    x:Name="Images"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Spacing="5" />
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="2"
            Padding="20,0"
            BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA">
            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                HeightRequest="40"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                WidthRequest="30">
                <Image.Source>
                    <OnPlatform
                        x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                        Android="camera"
                        WinPhone="Icons/camera.png"
                        iOS="Icons/camera.png" />
                </Image.Source>
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ImagePost_OnTapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

After Keyboard Popup see Image

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your layout codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [SoftInput to AdjustResize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) in order for Android to resize the views so they stay visible. In Forms, you can do this with the [platform specifics feature](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/platform-specifics/consuming/#soft_input_mode) in Forms 2.3.3.

Check out [this Gist on how to do this in OnCreate()](https://gist.github.com/jimmgarrido/e36033b26f01e8da091fd321d41d991a#file-forms-2-3-3). Note the workaround that's needed to remove an underlay added to the status bar in API 21+.

Comment: I have using this but when we go  back without hiding keyboard than half screen not show @jimmgarr

Comment: How we do same things in Ios? @jimmgarr

Comment: On iOS you will need to use a custom renderer so you can respond to the keyboard appearing and resize the view, [as seen here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/95846/#Comment_95846). As for the Android issue you mentioned, I'm not sure I understand. Can you create [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thanks!